# ExtJS 6: Should I use the config object?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm building an application with ExtJS 6.
I've already read the guides, tutorials and best practice tips.
But what I dont understand yet is, why should I use the config object?

With config:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.foo.Bar', {
    extends: 'Ext.window.Window',

    ...

    config: {
        title: 'My title'
    }
});
```

Without config:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.foo.Bar', {
    extends: 'Ext.window.Window',

    ...

    title: 'My title'
});
```

Both are working as expected.
Can anyone tell me the difference and possible benefits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's all described in the [Class System](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/guides/core_concepts/classes.html) guide:

> - Configurations are completely encapsulated from other class members
> - Getter and setter methods for every config property are automatically generated into the class prototype during class creation
>     if methods are not already defined.
> - The auto-generated setter method calls the apply method (if defined on the class) internally before setting the value. You may override
>     the apply method for a config property if you need to run custom logic
>     before setting the value. If your apply method does not return a
>     value, the setter will not set the value. The update method (if
>     defined) will also be called when a different value is set. Both the
>     apply and update methods are passed the new value and the old value as
>     params.

Comment: You're right. I should have read more carefully. Thank you anyway!